# WP8 Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: windows, object, windows-phone-8, reference

On the MainPage.xaml I try to set banner ad. It works 100% but it displays an error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Here's the line of code with the error:

```
<GoogleAds:AdView AdUnitID="ca-app-pub-AAAAA" Format="SmartBanner" Visibility="Visible" Margin="0,688,0,0"/>
```

Please help me,
Thank you,
Dvir

Comment: Why do you use `Visibility`, this control will be set to `Visible` by default.

Answer (score 0):

change format of ad type 
`Format="Banner"` then check it

Comment: wow I asked this a year ago. This is pretty cool you saw it now. not relevent anymore. I just kept it there since it was working